# Java size of long type

Tags: java, jvm

On [Oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html) I have read:

> You should avoid the use of  longs if at all possible since longs have different sizes on different operating systems even in 64-bit.  Windows 64-bit platforms define longs to be 4 bytes but most Unix operating systems specify that longs are 8 bytes in size.

1. What does this quote mean? When I want to store value more than ~2^31, how JVM store this value?
2. In calculations, JVM use RAX, or EAX register?

I know about `BigInteger` but i'm interested in primitive long type.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything until you provide the missing part after the 'but'.  A *Java* long is always 64 bits regardless of the platform, and there is no way which register it's can possibly affect you.

Comment: The next part is about unix not windows, how it is provide that java long is 64 bits?

Comment: Because that's the way it is defined.

Comment: Your quote is taken out of context.  It refers to porting 32-bit _native_ code to 64-bit, which is not written in Java.

Comment: Please take more care before posting on Stack Overflow. You misread some text which clearly refers to C/C++ coding, not Java. Either that, or you are trolling, in which case: Well done (but not welcome).

Answer (score 4):

You have taken the quote out of context.  The full context is this:

> ### 64-bit Java
>
> ### How is native code affected?
>
> ...
>
> When porting 32-bit native code to 64-bit Java platforms, you will
>   need to modify you code to be 64-bit clean.  This involves examining
>   your C/C+ + code and looking for code that assumes the size of a
>   pointer to be 4 bytes or that a pointer can be cast and stored in an
>   integer.   Long data types are also troublesome when porting 32-bit
>   code.  **You should avoid the use of  longs if at all possible since
>   longs have different sizes on different operating systems even in
>   64-bit.  Windows 64-bit platforms define longs to be 4 bytes but most
>   Unix operating systems specify that longs are 8 bytes in size.**  For
>   more details, refer to the links below under learning more about
>   64-bit programming.

To answer your questions:

> Java size of long type?

The Java `long` type is 64 bits on all platforms.

> What does this quote mean?

It is self evident, but it is clearly NOT referring the the Java `long` type.  It is referring to the use of the C or C++ `long` type in native code.

> When I want to store value more than ~2^31, how JVM store this value?

In Java code, use `long`.  It works.  The JVM implementation takes care of it in different ways on different platforms.  Don't worry about it.

In C / C++ native code you have a problem if you want your code to be portable.  But the original article provides you with links to help you get your head around the problem.

> In calculations, JVM use RAX, or EAX register?

The Java language specification **requires** that `long` has a 64 bit (no less, no more) representation, and that all `long op long` arithmetic is performed with at least 64 bits of precision so that the answer is the same on all platforms.

The actual implementation depends on the platform.  The JVM / JIT compiler will (most likely) chose registers and instructions that are most efficient for the current platform.

Bear in mind that the JVM you run on a 32 bit Windows Intel platform is different to one for a 64 bit Windows Intel platform, or Solaris, ARM, and so on.  For many of those platforms there are no registers called RAX and EAX.

But if you really need to know, look at the source code, or use the JVM option for dumping the native code emitted by the JIT compiler.